Unable to get JOB's back after jenkins version update
I can logIN but unable to get jobs after version update. I have updated my jenkins in below mentioned order 2.361.2 -> 2.375.1->2.375.4->2.387.1->2.387.2->2.387.3->2.401.1->2.401.3
I would like you all to look into the error logs as it is showing jobs we cannot read but I have given 777 permission.
[2024-09-09 09:21:39.707+0000 [id=38] SEVERE jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading item UAT com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) at hudson.util.XStream2$CompatibilityMapper.realClass(XStream2.java:452) at hudson.util.xstream.MapperDelegate.realClass(MapperDelegate.java:46) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47) at your text com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:135) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1464) at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:230) at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:201)
